# MySQL doesn't group 'text' cell correctly?

Tags: mysql

I have code that doesn’t work correctly:

```
SELECT tbl2.entry_id, tbl2.field_id_2, group_concat(DISTINCT tbl2.tag_name SEPARATOR ', ') FROM
    (SELECT e.entry_id, e.field_id_2, tbl1.tag_name

      FROM (exp_channel_data e)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT te.entry_id, tag.tag_id, tag.tag_name FROM exp_tag_entries te, exp_tag_tags tag WHERE te.tag_id = tag.tag_id) tbl1
      ON (e.entry_id = tbl1.entry_id) 
     WHERE e.entry_id IN (371, 373)) tbl2
    GROUP BY tbl2.entry_id, tbl2.field_id_2
```

It returns:

```
371;<p>...</p>;digital strategy
371;<p>...</p>;seo
371;<p>...</p>;inbound marketing
373;<p>...</p>;infographic, strategy, social media
```

but shoud be:

```
371;<p>...</p>;digital strategy, seo, inbound marketing
373;<p>...</p>;infographic, strategy, social media
```

Please, help me solve this problem. Type of 'field_id_2' cell is text, that have multiline value.

For example, [row with entry_id = 371 is here on PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/VPUkmwXy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 GROUP BY  tbl2.entry_id
```

instead of

```
 GROUP BY tbl2.entry_id, tbl2.field_id_2
```

and change this

```
 group_concat(DISTINCT tbl2.tag_name SEPARATOR ', ')
```

to

```
group_concat(tbl2.tag_name SEPARATOR ', ')
```

Comment: In this case result is right. hm.. How can I select value (field_id_2), that doesn't involved in GROUP BY operator? Is it cheat?